# How count missed call or reject call in android studio

Tags: java, android

Here I make a call from my app and I want to count missed or reject call
and I use a counter `(counterNoiseCalling)` to count missed or reject call but in node in Firebase counter still always equal 0 and I don't know why.

```
private class MyPhoneListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    private boolean onCall = false;
    String userNameCalling = UserDetails.username;
    int counterNoisingCall = 0;


    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    switch (state) {

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // phone ringing...
                Toast.makeText(Call.this, incomingNumber + " calls you", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

                // one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold
                Toast.makeText(Call.this, "on call...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(!onCall) {
                    //because user answer the incoming call
                    Toast.makeText(Call.this, "The call is being answered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    // reject call or missed call
                    Toast.makeText(Call.this, "Number Busy Or No Reply", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    counterNoisingCall++;
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                // in initialization of the class and at the end of phone call
                // detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
                if (onCall == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(Call.this, "restart app after call to Users List", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // restart our application to return to Our Contact
                    Intent restart = new Intent(Call.this , Users.class);
                    restart.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(restart);
                    onCall = false;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        Firebase childRef = mRootRef.child(userNameCalling);
        childRef.setValue(counterNoisingCall);

    }
}
```

Comment: can you debug and see, if it is going inside `else` block ?

Comment: @Ravi  i try this but by write Toast and it's not appear so it's not going inside else and i don't know why

Comment: @Ravi i want count number of reject or missed call but it's not going inside else

Comment: You seem to never set the onCall variable to true.

Comment: @algrid no i do it 
                    if(!onCall) {
                        //because user answer the incoming call
                        Toast.makeText(Call.this, "The call is being answered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        onCall = true;
and still counter = 0

Answer (score 0):

If you can debug and see that counterNoisingCall variable is not 0 then the problem seem to be related to Firebase.

I guess that may be is related to security rules. Maybe the user does not have permission write on the Firebase node.

I would put a complete listener on setValue to see that the command completed with success.

Try this.

```
Firebase childRef = mRootRef.child(userNameCalling);
childRef.setValue(counterNoisingCall).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("",task.getException().getMessage());
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read":true,
    ".write":true
  }
} this is rule of database but still counter not update in Firebase

Comment: Could you place a breakpoint inside the onComplete method to check what is the result of the firebase setValue call?